# Android studio device log level continuous print

Tags: android, android-studio

On android studio, when I plug a device in, the log cat keeps continuously printing device information to the console and it makes it difficult to see errors or logs I have set in the code. I have my log level set to "error" but this still seems to show all the device data anyways.

Attached is a screenshot:

[image]

If anyone has figured out how to disable the device console printing that would be great.

Comment: If you have your app running it should automatically chose the debugging application. But if not do it yourself. Logcat will log everything unless you specify your app.

Comment: Ohh and if the running lines just annoy you click on something else like To-Do